# Any core/real reference to *assret* as alias to *assert*

Tags: python, testing, mocking

I see it mentioned in a few places, all appear to stem from same issue filed against python core:

https://bugs.python.org/issue21238
https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.mock.html (unsafe kwarg)
https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/9cff6dd4dd676f15c7f99060ebb29d72a5482a6b

Is there a precedent for this spelling?

It appears intentional, but there's nothing else in the docs pointing to such use.

Comment: I'm not sure quite what you're asking - the point is, it's an easy mistype, and you don't want that to be quietly swallowed by the mocking. See the last two comments in that bug report.

Comment: Yes there are 2 new comments because I asked; but it is the first time I ever see such typo. Google doesn't produce many hits either. Is it well-known, or patcher's invention?

Comment: So is your question *"has anyone ever mistyped `'assert'` as `'assret'`?*"?

Comment: I suppose you are right. My original question was wider (is that an **alias** or a **joke**?) but now it pretty much comes down to how common of a **typo** it is?

Comment: Then I don't know how you'd answer it, except tautologically (i.e. *"common enough to be special-cased in `unittest.mock`"*!) I guess the probability of any given typo would vary by things like keyboard layout and the native language of the typist, but I'm not aware of any corpus or tool you could use to establish a particular case.

Comment: I've just seen this `assret` in unittest docs. It looks it's there just for case that anyone mispells `assert`. I think I've spent much more time figuring out WTF this `assret` is than the total sum of time spent fixing typos when spelling `assert` in my life. Is Python going to introduce `imort` as an alias for `import` too?

Comment: Looking at history, 'asert', 'aseert' and 'assrt' were also added to the code after checking Google's code base - [commit 4662fa9](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/4662fa9bfe4a849fe87bfb321d8ef0956c89a772)